# Can't view SIM contacts in android sdk

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I'm testing my application on ZTE mobile phone.

This is the piece of code I'm trying to run

```
Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
startActivityForResult(i, PICK_REQUEST);
```

It gives me phone contacts only. I want both phone and SIM contacts.

I've tried this code on Huawei phone and it works well, but not on a ZTE phone.

Answer (score 1):

try this

`Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI);             startActivityForResult(i, PICK_REQUEST);`

Comment: It crashes as Contacts.CONTENT_URI seems deprecated :(

Comment: did you add the permission in manifest.xml?
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

Comment: This is the permission I use.     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>